# Why isn't the bits shifting in this PIC assembler code?

Tags: assembly, pic

I just started to familiarize myself with PIC assembler and trying out shifting bits and lighting LEDs accordingly.

I am using a Xpress DM164140 development board with MPLAB X IDE.

I have 4 LEDs on RA0-RA3.
I want to light them one by one with shifting the R5 "user" register's value and assinging it to the PORTA register.

This is the assembly code I am using. Without the use of the DELAY subroutine all the 4 LEDs light up, but when I use the DELAY subroutine the RA3 will not light up. The shifting works until RA3.

So the problem must be in the DELAY subroutine somehow. Can't figure it out.
I have also tried lslf and addwf instructions to try to implement the desired behaviour but no luck so far.

Does anyone have a clue why is this happening?

Thanks in advance!

```
    ; Assembly source line config statements

#include "p16f18855.inc"

; CONFIG1
; __config 0x3FEC
 __CONFIG _CONFIG1, _FEXTOSC_OFF & _RSTOSC_HFINT1 & _CLKOUTEN_OFF & _CSWEN_ON & _FCMEN_ON
; CONFIG2
; __config 0x3FFF
 __CONFIG _CONFIG2, _MCLRE_ON & _PWRTE_OFF & _LPBOREN_OFF & _BOREN_ON & _BORV_LO & _ZCD_OFF & _PPS1WAY_ON & _STVREN_ON
; CONFIG3
; __config 0x3FFF
 __CONFIG _CONFIG3, _WDTCPS_WDTCPS_31 & _WDTE_ON & _WDTCWS_WDTCWS_7 & _WDTCCS_SC
; CONFIG4
; __config 0x3FFF
 __CONFIG _CONFIG4, _WRT_OFF & _SCANE_available & _LVP_ON
; CONFIG5
; __config 0x3FFF
 __CONFIG _CONFIG5, _CP_OFF & _CPD_OFF

 ;user define registers @ bank0   
R1 equ 0x20
R2 equ 0x21
R3 equ 0x22
R4 equ 0x23
R5 equ 0x24
R6 equ 0x25

RES_VECT  CODE    0x0000            ; processor reset vector
    GOTO    START                   ; go to beginning of program

; TODO ADD INTERRUPTS HERE IF USED

MAIN_PROG CODE                      ; let linker place main program

START
    CLRW
    MOVLB 0x11 ;select bank17 to change clock freq of HFINT1
    ;(high frequency internal oscillator)
    MOVLW 0x06
    MOVWF OSCFRQ    ;clock divider of 32 = 1MHz frequency

    MOVLB 0x00  ;move 0x00 to BSR aka select bank0, where TRISA reg is located     
    MOVLW 0xF0  
    MOVWF TRISA ;RA0-3 to output and RA4-RA7 to input
    MOVLW 0x01 ;00000001
    MOVWF R5
    MOVWF PORTA


MAIN
    CALL DELAY  ;delay to see the blinking
    bcf STATUS,C    ;clear carry bit
    rlf R5,1    ;shift contents of R5 by 1 to the left and save it to R5
    MOVF R5,0   ;move shifted R5 to W
    movwf PORTA ;move W to PORTA

    GOTO MAIN


;1 instruction cycles takes 4 clock cycles
;count to 250000@1MHz clock to get 1s delay
DELAY
    MOVLW 0x08  ;8
    MOVWF R1
DELAY_1
    MOVLW 0xFA  ;250
    MOVWF R2
DELAY_2
    MOVLW 0xFA  ;250
    MOVWF R3    
DELAY_3
    DECFSZ R3   ;decrease R2
    GOTO DELAY_3    
    DECFSZ R2   ;decrease R1
    GOTO DELAY_2
    DECFSZ R1   ;decrease R1
    GOTO DELAY_1
    RETURN

    END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I can see you have enabled the *watchdog timer*. Probably the *watchdog timer* has reset the MicroController before the 4th LED had lightened up.

So you must clear the *watchdog timer* somewhere in the main loop.

Put the instruction...

```
CLRWDT
```

after the label `MAIN`.

Answer (score 1):

May be it's too late, but anyway.
For outputs you must use LATx command. So replace both strings with PORTA to LATA.